# Android Build Failing with Command, but not in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, command-line

I'm learning React Native and all of sudden my Android build has started to fail. When I type the command 'react-native run-android' the build fails with following error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s Could not install the app on the device, read the
>   error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I have closed and re-opened the terminal, emulator, and Android Studio and made sure that the emulator is running before typing the command. But the build still fails. However if I go into Android Studio and click the 'Play' button (Run App), and the build succeeds and my App is displayed on the Android emulator.

I have also tried copying my project to another folder and all of the same errors still occur. Not a pressing issue, more just of an annoyance so if you have any suggestions that'd be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Same error occurs for me when i change gradle version in build.gradle file.
This error of NullPointerException occurs when the version in build.gradle does not match the version installed in your project root folder.
Then change to the same version resolved the error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)